# How to display array of split elements using LINQ

Tags: linq, ienumerable, console.writeline

I have this simple code

```
string[] sequences = {"red,green,blue","orange","white,pink"};

var allWords = sequences.Select(s => s.Split(','));

foreach (var letter in allWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(letter);
}
```

The problem is that in output I get System.String[] insted of splitted array. 
How to display result at console?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectMany` if you want an array of strings and not an array of arrays of strings.

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/0vsjfN

`SelectMany` concatenates the lists, which are generated by using `.Split(',')`, into a single list.